# Codeigniter (or PHP) removes parts of query string

Tags: php, database, codeigniter-3

I have a site based on Codigniter-3.0.4.
The ODBC database queries has been working fine for years.
Or so i thought. Yesterday I discovered that it just strips all parts of the query binding string that is between `%00` and `%1F` (ASCII control characters). For example `x%11y%z` becomes `xy%z`.

```
$sql = "SELECT TOP 100 "
        . "D1001 as 'part_number', "
        . "D1021 as 'description', "
        . "D1063 as 'hs_code' "
        . "FROM PULAGER "
        . "WHERE "
        . "D1001 LIKE ? OR "
        . "D1021 LIKE ? "
        . "ORDER BY D1001";

$contains = 'x%11y%z';
$sql_result = $this->db->query($sql, array($contains, $contains));
return $this->db->last_query();
```

Returns:

`SELECT TOP 100 D1001 as 'part_number', D1021 as 'description', D1063 as 'hs_code' FROM PULAGER WHERE D1001 LIKE 'xy%z' OR D1021 LIKE 'xy%z' ORDER BY D1001`

If I replace the questions marks with the search string manually it works fine. But I'm not sure about security issues or other consequences when not using the query binding.

Any suggestions on how I should solve this?